# Создание траектории полёта

Tags: геометрия, график, координаты

Ещё один вопрос по геометрии, в которой я очень плох
Как создать траекторию полёта снаряда в трёхмерном пространстве, имея начальные координаты и координаты цели в формате (x; y; z)?
Моя реализация кода для полёта может двигаться только по прямой, поэтому нужны дополнительные точки полёта для красивой траектории, а значит, как я понимаю, нужно строить график функции, даже два(для x; y и z; y), которые будут объединяться в трёхмерное пространство

Примерный рисунок того, как я это понимаю:[image: 1]
Вопрос в том, какая должна быть функция графика чтобы это построить? Положение точек в координатной плоскости могут отличаться, например начальные точки вряд-ли будут стоят в 0 0 0, а цель может иметь отрицательную высоту и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

В общем виде это называется движение «тела брошенного под углом к горизонту».
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На графике изображен вектор начальной скорости `V0`, в свою очередь для рассчетов он раскладывается(проецируется) на оси Х и У. Проекция `V0` на ось Х - `V0x`, проекция на ось У - `V0y`.

Эти проекции нужны для того, чтобы разложить сложное, казалось бы, движение на два простых и решить стандартной формулой.

**Формула**

```
х=х0+V0*t+0.5*(a*t^2)
```

х - координата точки в результате движения

х0 - начальная координата точки

V0 - проекция начальной скорости на ось

t - время движения

a - ускорение

Собственно, заменяете иксы на любую из нужных координат(х,у,z) и все работает как надо.

Перед тем, как пользоваться формулой - определим что влияет на перемещение по осям.

**Для оси Х**

Тут только проекция начальной скорости на ось `Х`

**Для оси Y**

Проекция V0 на ось

Ускорение свободного падения(g=9.8м/с^2)

*Из-за того, что ускорение направлено в противоположную сторону направлению оси - в расчетах используется со знаком минус*

Конкретно в этом случае с использованием формулы получаем, что Х определяется:

```
х = 0 + V0x*t + 0.5*(0*t^2)
```

То есть просто `x=V0x*t`

У определяется так:

```
у = 0 + V0y*t - 0.5*(g*t^2)
```

**Теперь к частному случаю определения начальных скоростей для попадания в точку:**

x = x0 + V0x*t

y = y0 + V0y*t - 0.5*(g*t^2)

Попробуем из обоих уравнений выделить `t`, тогда:

```
t = (x-x0)/V0x
```

(через виета или дискриминант) `t1 = V0y + (V0y^2 - 2*(y-y0))^0.5`

```
t2 = V0y - (V0y^2 - 2*(y-y0))^0.5
```

Два значения, т.к. может быть попадание в точку при движении вверх(до достижения максимальной высоты) и при движении вниз(после достижения максимальной высоты)

Таким образом, `t2` - не очень красивый вариант, т.к. траектория представляет собой прямую, откажемся от него.

Перед тем, как вовсе забыть о существовании `t2` - добавим записи в  ОДЗ:

Исходя из корня в t1 и t2, вносим в ОДЗ:

```
V0y^2 - 2*(y-y0) >=0
```

Из этого получается:

```
V0y >= (2*(y-y0))^0.5

V0y <= (2*(y-y0))^0.5
```

Также исходя из того, что время не может быть < 0:

```
V0y >= (V0y^2 - 2*(y-y0))^0.5
```

Добавим в ОДЗ также информацию по X:

```
V0x!=0

(x-x0)/V0x>0
```

**Объединяем оба уравнения (t и t1) для получения функции**

```
(x-x0)/V0x = V0y + (V0y^2 - 2*(y-y0))^0.5
```

Из него получаем зависимость между начальными скоростями

Можем из одз взять случайное число V0x и найти для него V0y или наоборот)

Как-то так, любые комментарии и дополнения приветствую. Рассмотрю и постараюсь дополнить ответ.

Comment: Если необходимо для трехмерного пространства - аналогично смотрите проекции на z, ну и имея формулы можете определить (x,y,z) в любой момент времени. В целом Z тоже должно быть без ускорения и сведется к формуле что я описал для Х.

Comment: Если ответ вам помог - отметьте его решением и при желании проголосуйте. В противном случае - жду ваши вопросы.

Comment: чтоб этот вопрос был решением найдите v0x и v0y такие чтоб было 1)попадание 2) траектория по у меняла направление

Comment: @eri траекторию поправил) Сейчас распишу попадание

Comment: v0 найти не так просто ( но минимальная будет самая красивая на мой взгляд) кстати g можно взять и не только 10.  в разных масштабах другие g могут оказаться красивее в анимации

Comment: @eri дополнил, что скажете?

Comment: Ну решение ещё не полное. В ответе у вас ещё 2 переменные. Траектория считается через 2 производные по t, насколько я помню

Comment: @eri так тут же нет единственного решения, так что от двух переменных не уйти. Фактически это просто зависимость.

Comment: можно найти минимум по `v0x^2+v0y^2`